# Search in elasticsearch using php curl

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch

I have make the application with elasticsearch and everything is running perfectly except the search using the php curl; the error is below

```
[match] query parsed in simplified form, with direct field name, but included more options than just the field name, possibly use its 'options' form, with 'query' element?]
```

but the same query is running perfectly in the command-line.

When I do some changes, I found this is occurring by the curl POST.

I am using the following code to run the php curl and tried the GET method too

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, strtoupper($method));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

and the query is

```
{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"bool":{"should":[{"match_phrase":{"name":"india"}}],"boost":16}},{"bool":{"should":[{"match_phrase":{"description":"india"}}],"boost":8}},{"bool":{"should":[{"match":{"name":{"query":"india","analyzer":"standard"}}},{"match":{"description":{"query":"india","analyzer":"standard"}}}],"boost":4}},{"match":{"name.ngram":[{"query":"india","analyzer":"standard"}]}},{"match":{"description":[{"query":"india","analyzer":"standard"}]}},{"match":{"name.ngram":[{"query":"india","analyzer":"standard","fuzziness":"auto"}]}},{"match":{"description":[{"query":"india","analyzer":"standard","fuzziness":"auto"}]}}],"boost":2}},"filter":{"and":[{"terms":{"type":["book"]}},{"range":{"price":{"from":"1","to":"100"}}}]}}},"from":0,"size":20,"filter":{"and":[]},"sort":[{"popularity":{"order":"desc","missing":"_last"}}]}
```

Comment: What is your query? I.e. what do you pass as `$params`?

Comment: @king_nak i have updated the question; please find the query now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution; below is the correct json

```
{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"bool":{"should":[{"match_phrase":{"name":"india"}}],"boost":16}},{"bool":{"should":[{"match_phrase":{"description":"india"}}],"boost":8}},{"bool":{"should":[{"match":{"name":{"query":"india","analyzer":"standard"}}},{"match":{"description":{"query":"india","analyzer":"standard"}}}],"boost":4}},{"match":{"name.ngram":{"query":"india","analyzer":"standard"}}},{"match":{"description":{"query":"india","analyzer":"standard"}}},{"match":{"name.ngram":{"query":"india","analyzer":"standard","fuzziness":"auto"}}},{"match":{"description":{"query":"india","analyzer":"standard","fuzziness":"auto"}}}],"boost":2}},"filter":[]}},"from":0,"size":20,"sort":[{"popularity":{"order":"desc","missing":"_last"}}]}
```

the problem is in the match query phase; I was appending the parameters in match query as nested array.

Now I have removed the nested array and append the options in match query phase as sequential array

Thanks guys for your co-opration

Answer (score 1):

Problem might be in you are using blank filters in your query dsl.

```
"filter": {
    "and":[]
}
```

Try without blank filters. Also top level filters are renamed in Elasticsearch 1.0 + version.

**Update Query DSL:**

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "should": [
                  {
                     "bool": {
                        "should": [
                           {
                              "match_phrase": {
                                 "name": "india"
                              }
                           }
                        ],
                        "boost": 16
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "bool": {
                        "should": [
                           {
                              "match_phrase": {
                                 "description": "india"
                              }
                           }
                        ],
                        "boost": 8
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "bool": {
                        "should": [
                           {
                              "match": {
                                 "name": {
                                    "query": "india",
                                    "analyzer": "standard"
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "match": {
                                 "description": {
                                    "query": "india",
                                    "analyzer": "standard"
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        ],
                        "boost": 4
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "name.ngram": [
                           {
                              "query": "india",
                              "analyzer": "standard"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "description": [
                           {
                              "query": "india",
                              "analyzer": "standard"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "name.ngram": [
                           {
                              "query": "india",
                              "analyzer": "standard",
                              "fuzziness": "auto"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "description": [
                           {
                              "query": "india",
                              "analyzer": "standard",
                              "fuzziness": "auto"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "boost": 2
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "and": [
               {
                  "terms": {
                     "type": [
                        "book"
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "range": {
                     "price": {
                        "from": "1",
                        "to": "100"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "from": 0,
   "size": 20,
   "sort": [
      {
         "popularity": {
            "order": "desc",
            "missing": "_last"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I have updated the query given by you and its also giving the same error